# what's the meaning of interface index at this specific ns3 code

Tags: ns-3

I am testing a ns3 program. And i met a problem similar to a example program in ns3 source code, see https://www.nsnam.org/release/ns-allinone-3.17.tar.bz2 file ns-3.17/src/lte/examples/lena-simple-epc.cc line 92.

i cannot understand the last parameter in code:

remoteHostStaticRouting->AddNetworkRouteTo (Ipv4Address ("7.0.0.0"), Ipv4Mask ("255.0.0.0"), 1);

why it is 1, not 0?

In my image, the var remoteHost has only one interface, so the max index value is 0. How comes out index 1 ??

I did a test to change value 1 to 0, then the remoteHost cannot send data out.

Under this fact, it is obvious that i misunderstood some theory here. What's it?

Answer (score 1):

sorry, it's all my careless.

the interface index 0 is the loopback.

the source code mentioned above tells this fact.

at the same time , it's advised to use GetNRoutes and GetRoute methods to see the route details of concerning nodes.